# wso2 php make errors

Tags: php, wso2

Im having issue installing the wso2 php framework. Folliwng the instructions from their website http://wso2.org/project/wsf/php/2.0.0/docs/install_guide.html#1.Installing_and_Running_on_Linux

Running opensuse 12.1

When I run make, i get the following errors and i have no idea how to proceed. any help will be appreciated

```
cp: target `/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/wsf_c/lib/' is not a directory
make[6]: *** [install-data-hook] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/wso2/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/sandesha2c/s                                                                                                                                                             rc/core'
make[5]: *** [install-data-am] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/wso2/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/sandesha2c/s                                                                                                                                                             rc/core'
make[4]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/wso2/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/sandesha2c/s                                                                                                                                                             rc/core'
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wso2/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/sandesha2c/s                                                                                                                                                             rc'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wso2/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/sandesha2c'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wso2/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are following the 2.0.0 doc, for the installation of 2.1.0. Pls follow the document [1] for the relevant version. I have recently installed WSF/PHP 2.1.0, on Ubuntu 10.04. [2] addresses a few issues I faced.

[1] - http://wso2.org/project/wsf/php/2.1.0/docs/install_guide.html
 [2] - http://kkpradeeban.blogspot.com/2012/01/installing-wso2-wsfphp-on-ubuntu-1004.html

Comment: Maybe this could be simply a general permissions issue, @user1412240 probably running 'make' as a non-sudoers user. So as a result the    /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/wsf_c/lib/ may not created by the script there for the error pops out.